# N level ExpandableListView

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a requirement to develop N level `ExpandableListView` in Xamarin.Android using MvvmCross. Can someone help me if they already have this kind of sample, which would be very helpful.

How can I achieve it? I am new to Xamarin and Mvvmcross.

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross had built-in support for expandable listviews since the 3.5.1-beta. This is added in this pull request: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/903

Comment: I want it for n level. But expandable listview is for 2 level only. Any suggestions

Comment: What is N level supposed to mean?

Comment: I have requirement for 3 levels now might be in future it will have 4 the level. I am planing to build it like this https://github.com/triggs/NLevelExpandableListView

Comment: Maybe you can try nesting expendeble listview?